# Хранение количества комментов и последнего коммента на стороннем сервере

Tags: вконтакте, vkontakte-api

Вот еще давно хотел решить эту задачу. Только ниже увидел темку про апи и вспомнил. В общем как юзер апи возвращает посл сообщение? Как его перехватить и записать в своей базе?

Comment: А можно поподробнее, какой метод api возвращает это сообщение?

Comment: его поидее возвращает виджет comment тока как его перехватить ума не придаю... вроде все логично, но нифига не понятно

Comment: На сколько мне известно виджет комментариев загружается в ifarame и если API вконтакта не позволяет получить последний комментарий (в чем я сомневаюсь) то на клиенте получить комментарий не получится, как вариант попытаться открыть src ifram'a через curl передав все необходимые заголовки и потом распарсить результат.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оказывается способ все таки есть, можно подписаться на событие-добавление/удаление комментария, и в обработчике события записывать сообщение в базу. Сделать это можно вот так:

```
VK.Observer.subscribe('widgets.comments.new_comment', function(num, last_comment, date, sign){
  // При добавлении нового комментария сработает эта функция 
  // num - количество комментариев
  // last_comment - текст последнего комментария
  // date - текущая дата в формате ISO 8601 (например, 2004-02-12T15:19:21+00:00)
  // sign - контрольная сумма md5 от конкатенации 4х строк: api_secret, date, num, last_comment.
  console.log(num);
  console.log(last_comment);
  console.log(date);
});
```

[Пруфлинк](http://vkontakte.ru/pages.php?o=-1&p=%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F+%D0%BE+%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5+%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B2)

Comment: То что надо, спасибо. Невнимательно я читал таки.